# AngularDart component not working with ng-repeat but other tags do

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I can do a ng-repeat with a input tag as follows.

```dart
<input ng-repeat="r in cmp.rooms track by $index" type="text" value="{{r.name}}" />
```

I made a AngularDart component called `<radio_component>`, so side by side.

```dart
<input ng-repeat="r in cmp.rooms track by $index" type="text" value="{{r.name}}" />
<radio_component ng-repeat="r in cmp.rooms track by $index" 
                        textLabel="{{r.name}}"></radio_component>
```

The textLabel is defined in my component as

```dart
@NgAttr('textLabel')
String textLabel;
```

Now it works with text if I set `textLabel="HELLO"`, but it does not work with `textLabel="{{r.name}}"`. I don't understand why? If I include `textLabel="{{r.name}}"` it doesn't work. Any clues?

---

To clarify the question and hopefully make it reproducible, here are some test files. The two files are test_component.dart and test_component.html

```dart
library minutesheet_component_radiobox;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@Component(
    cssUrl: 'http://localhost:8888/assets/css/admin/module.admin.stylesheet-complete.sidebar_type.no-sidebar.min.css',
    publishAs: 'test_component',
    selector: 'test_component',
    templateUrl: 'packages/minutesheet/component/test_component.html')

class TestComponent extends AttachAware with ShadowRootAware {

  // Chose either NgAttr or NgOneWay
  //@NgAttr("textLabel")
  //String textLabel;

  String _textLabel;
  @NgOneWay('textLabel') 
  String get textLabel => _textLabel; 

  set textLabel(String val) {
    print(val); _textLabel = val; 
  }

  void attach() {
  }

  void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot shadowRoot) {
  }
}
```

The html file for this component.

```dart
<div class="radio radioCheckbox">
<label class="radio-custom">
<i class="fa fa-circle-o" style="padding-top:1px"></i>
{{test_component.textLabel}}
</label>
</div>
```

Using these two files I have found that when I use the component the following is true.

If using @NgOneWay then null is passed into the set textLabel if I am using ng-repeat as follows:

```dart
<test_component ng-repeat="r in cmp.rooms track by $index" textLabel="{{r.name}}" />
```

If using @NgOneWay passing a string then null is also passed into the set textLabel:

```dart
<test_component ng-repeat="r in cmp.rooms track by $index" textLabel="HELLO" />
```

If using @NgAttr and passing the variable {{r.name}} then no value is shown on the HTML page.

If using @NgAttr and passing a "HELLO" then the word HELLO is shown on the HTML page.

---

If using @NgOneWay and using r.name in textLabel actually passes in the value to set textLabel on the component, however I do not see the value in the output HTML.

```dart
<test_component ng-repeat="r in cmp.rooms track by $index" textLabel="r.name" />
```

If using @NgTwoWay and using r.name in textLabel actually passes in the value to set textLabel on the component AND I do see the value in the HTML output.

```dart
<test_component ng-repeat="r in cmp.rooms track by $index" textLabel="r.name" />
```

Ok so @NgTwoWay works BUT now I cannot pass a normal string into the test component if I do it this way. If I then have.

```dart
<test_component textLabel="Hello there" />
```

Then I get this error.

Parser Error: 'there' is an unexpected token at column 7 in [Hello there]

Perhaps this is solved now, I am not sure if this is how it is supposed to work or if its working this way within my application due to some other code making it work strangely. Regardless, for me, it is at a point where I can get my application working, so I am happy enough for the time being.

---

Finally thanks to Gunter, it appears if the attribute of the component is named text-label and NOT textLabel AND @NgTwoWay is used, it works as expected in the first case. So its solved.

The moral of the story is, do not make component attributes with any upper case characters. (?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@NgAttr` doesn't work with camel case attribute names. See discussion below.

Comment: Do you mean on my component just change to @NgOneWay('textLabel')
  String textLabel; ? now I did that and textLabel="HELLO" does not work and textLabel="{{r.name}}" does not work. Is that what you would expect?

Comment: I added your component code into my source file and DartEditor tells me that `test_component` is an invalid selector. Can you try to change to `test-component`.

Comment: Yes I have done that, although, it doesn't change the outcome of the above notes I have added to my question.

Comment: Well the core of the problem is solved for me thanks, although its not how I would have expected it to behave. The only remaining issue that bothers me is the last item I added to the notes above. Do you have the same behaviours as me, within your test application?

Comment: I think `="{{'someText'}}"` should allow you to add literal text but now I think your original solution should have worked too because expressions between moustaches should be evaluated and then being passed. With `@NgAttr` `="xxx"` should pass the literal text and `="{{xxx}}"` should evaluate `xxx` and pass the result.

Comment: "I think your original solution should have worked too because expressions between moustaches should be evaluated and then being passed" - Are you able to get your test code to work in that case in the same way as my original code? (which is how I thought it was supposed to work). Maybe there's some strange difference between out code bases. My code runs within my larger application.

Comment: Currently I don't get by the 'Aw Snap!' :-/

Comment: it works for me with `NgAttr('text-label')` and `text-label="{{r.Name}}"`.

Comment: Yes your right it works with text-label but it doesn't work with textLabel. Is that what you find as well? So what rule am I breaking there?

Comment: There was a discussion about if Angular should convert between camel case and dashes. The behavior seems not to be consistent. You experienced yourself that it worked camel case when `@NgTwoWay` was used. I would file an issue.

Comment: Yes I guess I should file it as a issue, there's two things that bother me about this, one is that I was stuck without it working and no idea of why for a long time, so I resorted to using static's around in my code. Secondly, other people might fall into the same trap. I don't mind what they do, but give me a meaningful error which leads me to a solution OR be permissive and allow it.